# "alert" is not defined when running www.jshint.com

Tags: javascript

I fixed this by simply adding `var alert;`  However, is this what I should be doing to get the pesky error message to go away?  Here is the fix.  Here is the fail on [www.jshint.com](http://www.jshint.com/reports/71017).

I'm trying to learn from the error it throws..not necessarily make them go away.

```
(function () {

"use strict";

var alert;  //  added this in to fix

function initialize_page()
  {
  alert ("hi");
  }

addEventListener('load', initialize_page);

})();
```

Comment: @zzzzBov http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/2011/03/jslint-vs-jshint/

Comment: jslint is a syntax checker and it gives you feedback. If you use vim I recommend you install it.

Comment: I ran your code without any problems

Comment: @epascarello, good read, however i agree with Crockford's quote.

Comment: @zzzzBov Some people drink Crockford's KoolAid, some people don't. :)

Comment: @epascarello, some people use MLA citation format others use APA, it's more important to (1) be consistent in what format you use and (2) understand the pros and cons with the selected format. I'd never heard of jshint before, which is why i asked my original question.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[This](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#environments) documentation says the following about the `browser` option:

*This option defines globals exposed by modern browsers: all the way from good ol' document and navigator to the HTML5 FileReader and other new developments in the browser world.
Note: this option doesn't expose variables like alert or console. See option devel for more information.*

and the following about the `devel` option:

*This option defines globals that are usually used for logging poor-man's debugging: console, alert, etc. It is usually a good idea to not to ship them in production because, for example, console.log breaks in legacy versions of Internet Explorer.*

You have *browser* enabled and *devel* disabled. You can control these with checkboxes under "Assume" on the jshint original page. I also recommend heeding the warning in the documentation ;-)

Comment: I just click the development box on jshint.com, the options must be for the non-online version.

Comment: In JSLint for Visual Studio, the checkbox value is "Assume development globals"

Comment: You can also set this option in your local .jshintrc file.

Answer (score 69):

Instead of

```
alert('message')
```

you should use

```
window.alert('message');
```

Because this method [is defined in `window` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert).

This of course assumes you have `browser` option set to `true` in your `.jshintrc`, so this way jshint will know window object is exposed.

```
"browser"       : true,     // Standard browser globals e.g. window, document.
```

*The same thing happens with `confirm()`.

Comment: This is the only solution that keeps browser:true.  In my opinion, that makes this the best solution.

Comment: I concur, this is the immediate solution.

Answer (score 25):

Set "devel:true" in the Options. This enables things like Alert, console, etc.

See documentation here: http://jshint.com/docs/options/

Comment: Thank you, this was my issue and adding this config option fixed it immediately!

Answer (score 2):

Use `.jshintrc` file or <kbd>CTRL + ,</kbd> in **VS Code**, to edit options for **jshint**.

in js alert(data.status); or window.alert(data.status);

```
"window": true,
"alert": true
```

or best

```
"devel": true,

{
"esversion": 6,
"browser": true,
"undef": true,
"varstmt": true,
"forin": true,
"unused": true,
"funcscope": true,
"lastsemic": true,
"moz": true,
"jquery": true,
"module": true,
"devel": true,
"globals": {
    "window": true,
    "document": true,
    "console": true,
    "alert": true
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
function prod(arr) {
    let largest = 0;
    let secondLargest = 0;
    const len = arr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > largest) {
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = arr[i];
        }
        else if (arr[i] < largest && arr[i] > second_largest) {
            secondLargest = arr[i]
        }
    }
    return largest * secondLargest;
}

console.log(prod([2, 4, 7, 8]));
```

Answer (score 0):

in Visual Code, for individual file or without `.jshintrc` add `globals name`

```
"use strict";
/* globals alert */
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of:

```
alert('message')
```

I use:

```
var alert = window['alert'];
```

Answer (score -5):

try passing window object in :

```
(function (global) {

"use strict";

var alert;  //  added this in to fix

function initialize_page()
  {
  global.alert ("hi");
  }

addEventListener('load', initialize_page);

})(window);
```

Comment: Needs to set devel:true, not just browser:true. See documentation here: http://www.jshint.com/options/

Comment: This is a very ugly solution to such a small problem.

Comment: This can be done with the `devel: true` of jshint directive, instead of adding additional code

Answer (score -7):

declare alert as variable and it will work without any settings:

for example:

```
var alert;

alert('hello world');
```