# Unknown JSLint Errors

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm getting the following errors from JSLint, and I can't understand them:

-All questions have been answered-

Any help on any of these?

```
use /*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
function submit() {
    "use strict";
    document.forms.form.submit();
    var Mathematics = document.personal.Mathematics;
    var OMathematics = document.personal.OMathematics;
    var Sci = document.personal.Sci;
    var OSci = document.personal.OSci;
    var ELA = document.personal.ELA;
    var OELA = document.personal.OELA;
    var SS = document.personal.SS;
    var OSS = document.personal.OSS;
    var Elec1 = document.personal.Elec1;
    var OElec1 = document.personal.OElec1;
    var Elec2 = document.personal.Elec2;
    var OElec2 = document.personal.OElec2;
    var Elec3 = document.personal.Elec3;
    var OElec3 = document.personal.OElec3;
    var Owed = 0;
    function calc(n, o) {
        if (n >= 90) {
            Owed = Owed + 1;
            if (n >= 95) {
                Owed = Owed + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (o >= 80) {
            Owed = Owed + 0.5;
        }
        if (n > o) {
            Owed = Owed + 0.5;
        }
        if (n < o) {
            if (n > 95) {
                Owed = Owed - 0.25;
            }
        }
    }
    calc(Mathematics, OMathematics);
    calc(Sci, OSci);
    calc(ELA, OELA);
    calc(SS, OSS);
    calc(Elec1, Elec1);
    calc(Elec2, Elec2);
    calc(Elec3, Elec3);
    alert(Owed);
}​
```

Here is the code in context: http://jsfiddle.net/Aidoboy/AdzwC/

exceptions being used: "many var statements per function" and "messy white space"

Comment: Where is your code ? Post it here.

Comment: Always include relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: added the code and the exeptions I'm using

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> '`document`' was used before it was defined

You get this because the `document` variable has not been declared. You can tell JSLint that it should assume the code will run in a browser and therefore assume that things like `document` and `window` are pre-defined. You can do so with a JSLint comment at the top of your file:

```
/*jslint browser: true */
```

---

> `['form']` is better written in dot notation

Since you know the name of the property, there is no need to use square bracket notation:

```
document.forms.form.submit();
```

---

> '`alert`' was used before it was defined

You can use the `devel` option to prevent this error (you also use it to allow, for example, `console.log` calls):

```
/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */
```

---

> Unexpected `'​'`

There is some invisible character after the closing brace. Just delete that character to remove this error.

Comment: use `/*jslint browser: true, devel: true */` - not sure my edit of the above answer will go through

Comment: @olore - Thanks for the edit. I just modified it a bit to add it to the section on the `alert` error instead of the section on the `document` error.

Comment: Yay! It works! Now I think that there's a problem with my html. :P

Comment: For new visitors to this question, I'm putting together a collection of detailed JSLint error message explanations at http://jslinterrors.com. Try searching on there to find a solution to your error.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to avoid alert define error:

```
/*jslint devel: true */
```

[“alert” is not defined when running www.jshint.com - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8173484/746943)

> and the following about the devel option:
>
> This option defines globals that are usually used for logging
>   poor-man's debugging: console, alert, etc. It is usually a good idea
>   to not to ship them in production because, for example, console.log
>   breaks in legacy versions of Internet Explorer.