# 'Confirm' is not defined : error in javascript(on jenkins build or grunt analyze)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to Navigate away from this page? ');

if(!answer) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

[Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO3Nn.png)

Comment: Doesn't JSHint have some kind of "browser" option to define globals (such as `confirm`) exposed by modern browsers? I would think this would be a duplicate, though [the one I found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173364/alert-is-not-defined-when-running-www-jshint-com) is pretty old.

Comment: Adding var confirm will solve the problem. Need to declare as as an variable.